MyBatis Syntax error for xml SQL queries for delete operartion
My MyBatis XML looksl like this
<delete id="deleteAllById" parameterType="java.util.List">
    DELETE FROM `user`
    WHERE id IN
    <foreach collection="list" item="userId" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{userId}
    </foreach>
</delete>

And the error is
Error updating database. Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2 ### The error may exist in io/analog/cyclingservice/mapper/UserMapper.xml ### The error may involve io.analog.cyclingservice.mapper.UserMapper.deleteAllById-Inline ### The error occurred while setting parameters ### SQL: DELETE FROM user WHERE id IN ### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2 ; bad SQL grammar []
Any help on the correct syntax is appreciated.
I tried removing `` '' but same error.

That means the list is empty. You should enable DEBUG or TRACE level logging to see the actual SQL and parameters.
